# Isolate scope variable is undefined in nvd3 directive

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I'm facing the below error.

```
Error: d.values is undefined
chart/</<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js:6220:69
```

I'm unable to send the data from scope to html template using nvd3 directive.

I'm thinking that this is because of some version compatibility error.I'm really stuck over here.Can anyone please help me out ...

Comment: Can anyone please help me out ...

Comment: can you make a working jsfiddle i don't think anyone can help just by looking @ the error you have pasted